# SessionStorage doesn't update state with useEffect called on mount

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, session-storage

Pulling data from SessionStorage with useEffect and trying to pass them along to update useState on the component mount. Seems that the problem is **WHEN** the data is passed to the state since passing a fixed number does indeed update the state correctly.

What I'm actually seeing is that after the component is unmounted and then re-mounted the state (correctly) resets to initial value but the value set in SessionStorage is not getting passed along from useEffect.

Could the problem be that useEffect acts as componentDidMount and not componentWillMount?

On an unrelated note, SessionStorage does **not** persist on page refresh, which is strange since I thought that it only goes away when you close the tab

```
 const [movieCounter, setMovieCounter] = useState<number>(1)
  const [serieCounter, setSerieCounter] = useState<number>(1)
  console.log(movieCounter + ' state') // this logs 1 after re-mount


  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      //this works
      sessionStorage.setItem('abc123', JSON.stringify(movieCounter))
      sessionStorage.setItem('qwerty', JSON.stringify(serieCounter))
    };
  }, [movieCounter, serieCounter])


  useEffect(() => {
    const rehydrate1 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('abc123') || '{}')
    const rehydrate2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('qwerty') || '{}')
    setMovieCounter(rehydrate1)
    setMovieCounter(rehydrate2)

    // here if I pass a fixed number i.e. 4 updates state correctly to 4 
    // on mount
    // setMovieCounter(4)


    // this logs actual value pulled from sessionstorage
    console.log(rehydrate1 + ' json') 
  }, [])
```

The state on mount needs to be updated from the SessionStorage values.

**UPDATE**

ok, so I just noticed that if I pass a fixed number on the returned function of the first useEffect the value is getting passed to the state on every mount.

```
// this updates the state to 60 after every re-mount of the component

useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      sessionStorage.setItem('abc123', JSON.stringify(60))
      sessionStorage.setItem('qwerty', JSON.stringify(60))
    };
  }, [movieCounter, serieCounter])
```

I think I'm missing something simple here

Comment: What data is in sessionStoarge 'abc123'?

Comment: if you mean what type, it's a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so as I said "I think I'm missing something simple here". This was the case. I accidentally rehydrated the same SessionStorage slot twice, once with the correct updated data and once after with the stale/unused second useState

```
useEffect(() => {
    const rehydrate1 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('abc123') || '{}')
    const rehydrate2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('qwerty') || '{}')

    // here was the problem
    setMovieCounter(rehydrate1)
    setMovieCounter(rehydrate2)


    console.log(rehydrate1 + ' json') 
  }, [])
```

I'm sorry for the banality of the problem/solution guys

Answer (score 2):

- If you want to clean up something when you unMount from useEffect, you need to give the parameter an empty arrangement.
- JSON.parse is not good when handle number.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const rehydrate1 = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('abc123') || '1')
    const rehydrate2 = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('qwerty') || '1')

    setMovieCounter(rehydrate1)
    setMovieCounter(rehydrate2) // I think it is also wrong. setMovieCounter was called two times.

    return () => {
      sessionStorage.setItem('abc123', movieCounter)
      sessionStorage.setItem('qwerty', serieCounter)
    };
  }, [])
```

Comment: Well not passing `movieCounter` and `serieCounter` in the array will not update the sessionstorage.

Comment: If you want to update sessionStorage, remove return at your code. It will update every time when state change.

Comment: Yes. While this is correct (and the way I'm using it is kind of an anti pattern) since I included the two variables in the array the sessionStorage is still getting updated. This is not my problem as I have clearly stated in my question.SessionStorage is getting updated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sessionStroage use localStorage  as in useEffect component rerender and not able to maintain session.

```
    console.log(">>>>outside>>",localStorage.getItem('ltk'))
        // use local Storage
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch(url,{
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 
                    'x-access-token':localStorage.getItem('ltk')
                }
            })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(">>>>>",data)
                setUser(data)
            })
        },[])
```